# Expected Value of Matching $n$ Balls in $n$ Boxes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Lets say there is an experiment in which balls numbered $1,...,n$ are distributed at random in $n$ boxes, also numbered $1,...,n$ so that each box has exactly one ball. Thus, the total number of possible outcomes is $n!$. Let $S_n$ be the number of matches; a match occurs when the ball and the box containing it have the same number.

I want to find $E(S_n)$ and $Var(S_n)$. I'm having troubles identifying the problem mathematically.

Comment: I had an answer on my computer, but I had to go afk for a while. When I came back and finished up and submitted my answer, the question was closed. If you  add some [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960), maybe the question will be reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If $X_i$ is the number of the ball in the $i$-th box, then $S_n = \sum \limits_{i = 1}^n I\{X_i = i\}$. Now use standard arithmetic and the linearity of the expectation to determine $E[S_n]$ and $E[S_n^2]$.

Comment: So for $E[S_n]$ would it just be $(1/n!)^n$ and for $E[S^2_n]$ it would be the same?

Comment: No, this is very wrong.

Comment: Here is how I did it $E[S_n]=E[I{X_1=1}+...+I{X_n=n}]$ then for each term multiply the value of 1 by the probability of $i-th$ ball getting in the corresponding bin which is $1/n$

Comment: Then how did you get from this to $1/n!^n$?

Comment: It should of been $(1/n)^n$ but I couldn't edit my comment.

Comment: Again, wrong. You didn't apply the rules for the expectation, but just guessed what the answer might look like.

Comment: I see. I made a mistake by multiplying when I should of summed. So fixing this it would just be 1. That should fix what you pointed out

Comment: Yes, that's the correct value for the expectation.

Comment: The variance is a pain. I know a solution which uses the fact that the natural representation of the symmetric group is the composition of 2 irreducible representations, but that's using a sledgehammer. Any simpler approaches?

Comment: Expand the square and use $P(X_i = i, X_j = j) = \frac{1}{n(n-1)}$ for $i \ne j$.